# Merge two vectors of maps in clojure based on index

Tags: vector, merge, clojure, maps

I have two vectors of maps in clojure, and I wish to merge them so that it is a single vector of maps, but the maps at each index are merged. I was just wondering the best way to do this.

For example:

```
[{:sku "e1" :name "example1"} {:sku "e2" :name "example2"}]
[{:color "Blue" :price 9.99} {:color "Red" :price 15.99}]
```

Would be merged to:

```
[{:sku "e1" :name "example1" :color "Blue" :price 9.99} {:sku "e2" :name "example2" :color "Red" :price 15.99}]
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`mapv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) and [`merge`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge):

```
(mapv merge 
      [{:sku "e1" :name "example1"} {:sku "e2" :name "example2"}]
      [{:color "Blue" :price 9.99} {:color "Red" :price 15.99}])

=> [{:sku "e1", :name "example1", :color "Blue", :price 9.99} {:sku "e2", :name "example2", :color "Red", :price 15.99}]
```